# Points Lie On the Same Line in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: geometry

Say there are $3$ points: $A,B,$ and $C$, and we know each of their coordinates. I was told that all $3$ points lie on the same line (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) if you take the sum of the two shorter lengths and they equal the longer length. Why is this?

Comment: If $a<b<c$ then $c-a=c-b + b-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the Triangle inequality. WLOG let $C$ be the the middle point. Then from the Triangle ineqality we have that if and only if:

$$AC + BC > BA $$

we can construct a $\triangle ABC$.

So if C didn't lie on the segment $AB$ the upper inequality will hold. But this will violate the condition that is given:

$$AC + BC = BA$$

So this implies that C lies on the segment $AB$

Answer (score 1):

If the three points are on a line, then they can be expressed as $x_0+t d$ for various values of $t$, that is $A = x_0 + t_A d$, $B = x_0 + t_B d$ and $C = x_0 + t_C d$.

We may assume (by adjusting the $t$s as appropriate) that $d$ is of unit length. We may also assume (by relabelling, if necessary) that $t_C > t_B > t_A$, so, in particular, $A$ and $C$ are furthest apart.

Notice that the distance between $C$ and $A$ is $t_C-t_A$, and similarly for the pairs $(C,B), (B,A)$. Then we have $t_C-t_A = (t_C - t_B) + (t_B -t_A)$, which is the desired result.